# What to do about a series of almost-duplicates all related to a frequent error message

Tags: discussion

When I applied the information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9130365/1132334) to a problem I had today, there is this "Related" section of spot-the-difference duplicates:

[image]

And there are more, only 10 are shown. Clicking through just these 10, there will be two or three which are different or specific enough to keep, but IMO the rest could be merged into the first or deleted. Is that:

- feasible
- worth the effort and
- who can do it?

Comment: For the ones that are kept, I would think the titles should be edited so its clearer at a glance how they're different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just vote to close them as duplicates, if you think they're duplicates.  If/when they're closed as duplicates they can eventually be voted for deletion by users with the privilege, but that's less practical than getting them closed, as it requires more rep to have the privilege and posts get less attention for deletion than they do for closure.  The closure is also more important than the deletion, so that's not necessarily a bad thing either.

Comment: I've tried this in the past, however, I find when I flag older posts as duplicates, the flags almost always end up aging away.

Comment: @TotZam Couldn' t you theoretically ask the SOVCR to commit to closing the questions targetted?

Comment: @Icepickle I'm not a fan of chat rooms. I also don't think you should need to specifically elicit help each time you find a question you think should be closed. Flagging something should be enough if the close vote tool worked properly.

Comment: @TotZam It's not really a problem with the tool that not enough people vote to close questions that merit closure.  There isn't any way for the tool to deal with that.

Comment: @TotZam I am not saying that should always be done, however it could be done for very old questions, since it would possibly lead toa solution, whereas aged away flags don't really help anybody

Comment: My point really just was that while this solutions sounds nice and simple, I have not found it to work in the past, and this problem might need some extra attention if we want to really get it cleaned up.